Anomaly detection using CNN autoencoder along with gramian angular field image encoding for time series data
bit of an interesting question here. I have a CNN autoencoder model built using tensorflow that I am trying to detect anomalies with using kernel density estimation along with reconstruction error. This works fine for one dataset I am using (90% detection with 0.6% false positive), however with my most relevant one, it detects everything as an anomaly. I need some help to understand what is wrong with my model for this dataset. The model is not overfitting as the val_loss never starts increasing while loss is decreasing.
below are the values for normal and anom data. [0] = density mean, [1] density std, [2] reconstruction error mean, [3] reconstruction error std:
normal: (2822.07084922319, 1.3207919128364734e-10, 0.004408350901940139, 0.0006830073397453419)
anomalous: (-3017.546708702692, 4148.292151674365, 0.004043867258587852, 0.0015991246296969419)
I am using gramian angular fields generated. Below I will attach columns of the csv, an example row, detail on it, the autoencoder model, and the GAF generation script:
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import glob

# Check if GPU is available
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if physical_devices:
    print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))
    # Optionally set memory growth to avoid memory allocation issues
    for gpu in physical_devices:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
else:
    print("No GPU available, using CPU.")

# Define constants
MODEL_PATH = 'saved_autoencoder_model_falling.h5'
SIZE1 = 128
SIZE2 = 128 #stacked
batch_size = 64

# Define image generators for training, validation, and anomaly detection
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
'''datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    preprocessing_function=lambda x: x[:, :, :3]  # Ensure only 3 channels are used
)'''

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'GAF_IMG/TRAIN/',
    target_size=(SIZE1, SIZE2),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='input'
)

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'GAF_IMG/TEST/',
    target_size=(SIZE1, SIZE2),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='input'
)

anomaly_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'GAF_IMG/ANOMALY/',
    target_size=(SIZE1, SIZE2),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='input'
)

# Function to build the autoencoder model
def build_autoencoder():
    model = Sequential()
    # Encoder
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(SIZE1, SIZE2, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

    # Decoder
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])
    return model

# Check if the model is already saved, otherwise train a new one
if os.path.exists(MODEL_PATH):
    print("Loading saved model...")
    model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
else:
    print("Training new model...")
    model = build_autoencoder()
    history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=500 // batch_size,
        epochs=1000,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=75 // batch_size,
        shuffle=True
    )
    # Save the model after training
    model.save(MODEL_PATH)
    print(f"Model saved to {MODEL_PATH}")

# Display model summary
model.summary()

# The rest of your code continues...


# Get a batch of images to test the model
data_batch = []
img_num = 0
while img_num <= train_generator.batch_index:
    data = next(train_generator)
    data_batch.append(data[0])
    img_num += 1

predicted = model.predict(data_batch[0])

# Display random images and their reconstructions
image_number = random.randint(0, predicted.shape[0] - 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(data_batch[0][image_number])
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(predicted[image_number])
plt.show()

# Evaluate the reconstruction error for normal and anomaly images
validation_error = model.evaluate(validation_generator)
anomaly_error = model.evaluate(anomaly_generator)

print("Recon. error for validation data (normal):", validation_error)
print("Recon. error for anomaly data:", anomaly_error)

# Build the encoder model for latent space extraction
encoder_model = Sequential()
encoder_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(SIZE1, SIZE2, 3)))
encoder_model.layers[-1].set_weights(model.layers[0].get_weights())

encoder_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
encoder_model.layers[-1].set_weights(model.layers[2].get_weights())

encoder_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder_model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
encoder_model.layers[-1].set_weights(model.layers[4].get_weights())
encoder_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

encoder_model.summary()

# Calculate Kernel Density Estimation (KDE)
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

encoded_images = encoder_model.predict(train_generator)
encoder_output_shape = encoder_model.output_shape
out_vector_shape = np.prod(encoder_output_shape[1:])

encoded_images_vector = [np.reshape(img, (out_vector_shape,)) for img in encoded_images]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.2).fit(encoded_images_vector)

# Function to calculate density and reconstruction error
def calc_density_and_recon_error(batch_images):
    density_list, recon_error_list = [], []
    for img in batch_images:
        img = img[np.newaxis, :, :, :]
        encoded_img = encoder_model.predict(img)
        encoded_img = [np.reshape(img, (out_vector_shape,)) for img in encoded_img]
        density = kde.score_samples(encoded_img)[0]
        reconstruction = model.predict(img)
        reconstruction_error = model.evaluate(reconstruction, img, batch_size=1)[0]
        density_list.append(density)
        recon_error_list.append(reconstruction_error)

    return (
        np.mean(density_list), np.std(density_list),
        np.mean(recon_error_list), np.std(recon_error_list)
    )

train_batch = next(train_generator)[0]
anomaly_batch = next(anomaly_generator)[0]

uninfected_values = calc_density_and_recon_error(train_batch)
anomaly_values = calc_density_and_recon_error(anomaly_batch)
print(f'normal: {uninfected_values}')
print(f'anomalous: {anomaly_values}')


# Function to classify an image as normal or anomaly


def check_anomaly(img_path):
    try:
        # Open and convert the image to RGB to ensure 3 channels
        img = Image.open(img_path).resize((128, 128), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    except PermissionError as e:
        print(f"Permission denied: {e}")
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error opening image: {e}")
        return False

    img = np.array(img) / 255.0
    img = img[np.newaxis, :, :, :]  # Shape: (1, 128, 128, 3)

    encoded_img = encoder_model.predict(img)
    encoded_img = [np.reshape(img, (out_vector_shape,)) for img in encoded_img]
    density = kde.score_samples(encoded_img)[0]
    reconstruction = model.predict(img)
    recon_error = model.evaluate(reconstruction, img, batch_size=1)[0]

    if (
        density < uninfected_values[0] - 1 * uninfected_values[1]
        or density > uninfected_values[0] + 1 * uninfected_values[1]
        or recon_error > uninfected_values[2] + 1 * uninfected_values[3]
    ):
        return True  # Image is an anomaly
    else:
        return False



'''def check_anomaly(img_path):
    try:
        # Open and resize the image with updated resampling
        img = Image.open(img_path).resize((128, 128), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    except PermissionError as e:
        print(f"Permission denied: {e}")
        return False  # Return False for permission errors
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error opening image: {e}")
        return False  # Return False for other errors
    img = np.array(img)
    print(f"Image shape: {img.shape}")  # Add this line to debug

    img = np.array(img) / 255.0
    img = img[np.newaxis, :, :, :]

    encoded_img = encoder_model.predict(img)
    encoded_img = [np.reshape(img, (out_vector_shape,)) for img in encoded_img]
    density = kde.score_samples(encoded_img)[0]
    reconstruction = model.predict(img)
    recon_error = model.evaluate(reconstruction, img, batch_size=1)[0]

    if density < uninfected_values[0] - 3 * uninfected_values[1] or density > uninfected_values[0] + 3 * uninfected_values[1] or recon_error > uninfected_values[2] + 3 * uninfected_values[3]:
        return True  # Image is an anomaly
    else:
        return False  # Image is NOT an anomaly
'''
# Test the anomaly detection on all anomalous images
anom_image_paths = glob.glob('GAF_IMG/ANOMALY/images/*')
normal_file_paths = glob.glob('GAF_IMG/TEST/images/*')
correctly_identified = 0
false_id = 0
for img_path in anom_image_paths:
    if check_anomaly(img_path):  # If it returns True, it means an anomaly was correctly identified
        correctly_identified += 1

# Calculate and print the percentage of correctly identified anomalies
total_anomalies = len(anom_image_paths)



for img_path in normal_file_paths:
    if check_anomaly(img_path):  # If it returns True, it means an anomaly was incorrectly identified
        false_id += 1

# Calculate and print the percentage of correctly identified anomalies
total_normal = len(normal_file_paths)


if total_normal > 0:
    accuracy_percentage_normal = (false_id / total_normal) * 100
    print(f"Falsely identified anomalies: {false_id}/{total_normal} ({accuracy_percentage_normal:.2f}%)")
else:
    print("No anomalous images found for testing.")
    
if total_anomalies > 0:
    accuracy_percentage = (correctly_identified / total_anomalies) * 100
    print(f"Correctly identified anomalies: {correctly_identified}/{total_anomalies} ({accuracy_percentage:.2f}%)")
else:
    print("No anomalous images found for testing.")

csv data:
x,y,z,010-000-024-033,010-000-030-096,020-000-032-221,020-000-033-111,anomaly
16.13363583394,18.03632157313945,11.785301895672383,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0

GAF generation script
# Import necessary libraries
import os
from pyts.image import GramianAngularField
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm
# Load data
train_files = glob.glob("Falling-Dataset/data/train/*.csv")
test_files = glob.glob("Falling-Dataset/data/test/*.csv")

train_data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in train_files], ignore_index=True)
test_data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in test_files], ignore_index=True)

# Filter normal and anomalous events
train_data_normal = train_data[train_data['anomaly'] == 0]
train_data_anomaly = train_data[train_data['anomaly'] == 1]

# Split normal events into training and validation sets
train_data, val_data = train_test_split(train_data_normal, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
train_data = train_data.drop('anomaly', axis=1)
val_data = val_data.drop('anomaly', axis=1)
train_data_anomaly = train_data_anomaly.drop('anomaly', axis=1)

# Drop non-coordinate columns
columns_to_drop = ['010-000-024-033', '010-000-030-096', '020-000-032-221', '020-000-033-111']
train_data_coord = train_data.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
val_data_coord = val_data.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
train_data_anomaly_coord = train_data_anomaly.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)

# Normalize the data between -1 and 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
train_data_coord = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(train_data_coord), columns=train_data_coord.columns)
val_data_coord = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(val_data_coord), columns=val_data_coord.columns)
train_data_anomaly_coord = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(train_data_anomaly_coord), columns=train_data_anomaly_coord.columns)

# Set up the GAF transformer and parameters
gaf = GramianAngularField(method='summation')
timeStep = 14  # Set the time window to 14 timesteps

# Function to create GAF images for each 14-timestep window, stack them, and apply a color filter
def create_gaf_images_with_color(data, timestep, path, image_prefix, max_images=None):
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
    images = []

    # Loop over data in windows of 'timestep' size
    for i in range(0, len(data) - timestep + 1, timestep):
        # Initialize lists to hold GAF images for x, y, and z
        gaf_x_list = []
        gaf_y_list = []
        gaf_z_list = []

        # Loop to take 3 consecutive windows for each variable
        for j in range(3):
            window_x = data.iloc[i + j * timestep:i + (j + 1) * timestep, 0].to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)
            window_y = data.iloc[i + j * timestep:i + (j + 1) * timestep, 1].to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)
            window_z = data.iloc[i + j * timestep:i + (j + 1) * timestep, 2].to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)

            # Generate GAF images for each variable
            gaf_x = gaf.fit_transform(window_x)[0]
            gaf_y = gaf.fit_transform(window_y)[0]
            gaf_z = gaf.fit_transform(window_z)[0]

            # Append GAF images to their respective lists
            gaf_x_list.append(gaf_x)
            gaf_y_list.append(gaf_y)
            gaf_z_list.append(gaf_z)

        # Stack the GAF images vertically (3x12) for each variable
        stacked_gaf_x = np.concatenate(gaf_x_list, axis=0)  # Shape should be (36, 128)
        stacked_gaf_y = np.concatenate(gaf_y_list, axis=0)  # Shape should be (36, 128)
        stacked_gaf_z = np.concatenate(gaf_z_list, axis=0)  # Shape should be (36, 128)

        # Now stack the sets of GAF images horizontally (1x3 for each variable)
        combined_gaf_image = np.concatenate([stacked_gaf_x, stacked_gaf_y, stacked_gaf_z], axis=1)  # Shape (36, 384)
        combined_gaf_image = np.clip(combined_gaf_image, 0, 1)  # Ensure values are between 0 and 1

        # Resizing to 128x128
        combined_gaf_image_resized = np.array(Image.fromarray((combined_gaf_image * 255).astype(np.uint8)).resize((128, 128)))

        # Apply colormap to create an RGB image
        colored_image = cm.viridis(combined_gaf_image_resized / 255.0)[:, :, :3]  # RGB channels only
        img = Image.fromarray((colored_image * 255).astype(np.uint8))  # Convert to PIL Image

        # Save the image using PIL
        img.save(f"{path}/{image_prefix}_gaf_image_{i // timestep + 1}.png")
        images.append(img)

        # Check if we've reached the maximum number of images to save
        if max_images is not None and len(images) >= max_images:
            break  # Stop if we've reached the limit

    return np.array(images)

# Create directories if they do not exist
os.makedirs('GAF_IMG/TRAIN/images', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('GAF_IMG/TEST/images', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('GAF_IMG/ANOMALY/images', exist_ok=True)

# Create GAF images for each 14-timestep window in the training, validation, and anomaly data
train_gaf_images = create_gaf_images_with_color(train_data_coord, timeStep, path='GAF_IMG/TRAIN/images', image_prefix='train', max_images=500)
val_gaf_images = create_gaf_images_with_color(val_data_coord, timeStep, path='GAF_IMG/TEST/images', image_prefix='val', max_images=100)
anom_gaf_images = create_gaf_images_with_color(train_data_anomaly_coord, timeStep, path='GAF_IMG/ANOMALY/images', image_prefix='ANOM')


That is a lot of code. Try reducing it to those parts that are relevant to your question. Also this is probably not a programming question, so maybe ask this question at Cross Validated.
